# <select name = {{loop.index}}>

Tags: javascript, python, html, forms, jinja2

I need a way to post and gather the answers. I have thought of ***name={{loop.index}}*** but it does not work. Any idea?

EDIT: Forgot to say, I'm using Flask framework and Jinja2 template engine .

```
<h2>Trivia!</h2>
<form action="/trivia" method="post">
    <br>

    {% for question in questions %}

        <h3>{{question.text}}</h3>
        <ol>
            <li>{{question.option1}}</li>
            <li>{{question.option2}}</li>
            <li>{{question.option3}}</li>
        </ol>
        <select name={{loop.index}}>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>

    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: what value does come in its place?

Comment: Thanks, just solved. Forgot to `str()` when looking up the `answers = [request.form.get(str(i + 1)) for i in range(10)]` in the DOM.